# Unable to find a specification for `podName`

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, cocoapods-1.0.1

I am unable to find podSpec for any pod listed in my Podfile. My Podfile looks like this:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'MyTargetName' do
    pod 'Gloss'
    pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
    pod 'ICViewPager'
    pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField'
    pod "KCFloatingActionButton"
    pod "TSMessages"
end
```

Initially I got an error:

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `IQKeyboardManagerSwift`
```

I've tried removing IQKeyboardManagerSwift, but then I get another error:

```
[!] Unable to find a specification for `ICViewPager`
```

I've checked both of those projects, and they exist on cocoapods.org, and podspec exists on github as well as the pod repo. 
Everything started when I updated to Xcode 8.0 and Swift 3.0. Any idea what has gone wrong here?

EDIT:

I managed ti find a workaround that fixed issue related to downloading cocoapods:

```
use_frameworks!

target 'MyTargetName' do
    pod 'Gloss'
    pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift', :git => 'https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager'
    pod 'ICViewPager', :git => 'https://github.com/iltercengiz/ICViewPager'
    pod 'SkyFloatingLabelTextField’, :git => 'https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField'
    pod "KCFloatingActionButton”, :git => 'https://github.com/kciter/KCFloatingActionButton'
    pod "TSMessages”, :git => 'https://github.com/KrauseFx/TSMessages'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the source at the top of your `Podfile`?

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

Comment: It was not required before upgrading Xcode and Swift....why now? Cocoapods remained the same version (newest one) throughout the process.

Comment: Did adding it fix your issue? If so, I have no idea why it would have worked before but now suddenly stopped working without it.

Comment: I updated my answer with the workaround I've found. For the time being it works, but I don't thing this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Do these:

```
$ sudo rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/
$ rm -fr ~/.cocoapods/repos/master/
$ sudo rm -fr Pods/
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
$ pod setup
```

Then run `$ pod install` .. Hopefully It works